# Silverlight: Why is there space between these two elements?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-7

I'm using Silverlight 4 to develop a Windows Phone app. I have a control defined by the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="Thumbnail" Grid.Column="0" Width="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <!-- sometimes there's a hanging word in the headline that looks a bit awkward -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="Headline" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="23.333" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Teaser" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>
</Grid>
```

For some reason, there's a space between `Headline` and `Teaser`. Removing the `PhoneAccentStyle` doesn't help.

Why could this be? There's no margin or padding defined for those two elements. The first grid row's height is defined to be `Auto`. Doesn't that mean that it will only be as large as the content within it?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that sometimes `textBlock.Text` would include a `\n`. Removing those solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no space between the two `TextBlock`s, but between the actual letters and the border of the `TextBlock`. Try to compare your layout with two similar `TextBlock`s inside a `StackPanel`, it should be the same.

The `TextBlock` reserves space for all kinds of characters with their elevation and descent. The space you see comes from there.

Comment: Setting the background colour or adding borders to the textblocks will show if this is the case.

Comment: Adding a background color reveals that the textblock is correctly sized, but it has too much space beneath it in some cases. (Not all, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the image and the height is not defined in XAML. What is the height of the image?

Comment: I'm not sure... is it always necessary to define it in the XAML? I was hoping I could define the width, then the height would be whatever it wanted to without causing stretching.

Comment: No it's not necessary to define it. But the problem here is that both the image and the Headline are in Row 0, and the Teaser is in Row 1. If the height of the image is taller than the height of the text in the Headline, then there will be a space between the Headline and the Teaser because of the image.

Comment: Also, I'm seeing this issue for controls where the image is set to Visibility: Collapsed.